# Setting Google Tag Manager consent with react-gtm-module

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, react-gtm-module

In my React SPA, I use npm module [react-gtm-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module) to connect it to GTM. I can send events, using this syntax:

```
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event: 'calc_price_btn'
  })
```

but I am not sure if and how I can send [consent](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/consent#gtag.js) updates. Is it possible with this module, or will I have to use the standard gtag HTML snippet? Can `react-gtm-module` do everything that standard `gtag()` calls can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was missing was defining the `gtag()` function:

```
window.gtag = function(){
  window.dataLayer.push(arguments)
}
```

It confused me that the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/consent#gtag.js) did not include the `dataLayer.push()` calls—only the `gtag()` calls. After defining the function, the code snippets from the docs can be used right away.

Answer (score 3):

My advice, don't use `react-gtm-module` if you want to enable the google tag consent by default for your SPA react app. I don't think its possible at the moment.

I've been trying for the last 3 hours, including debugging with the tag assisant (go to google tag manager and click the Preview button, you can test your setup on localhost). But the problem is that the `react-gtm-module` does not add the default consent via the API and also has no way of updating the consent values.

Its not that hard to setup google tag manually and it will allow you to use their latest funcionalities without depending on a package with very little documentation

In step 5 you see that you need an extra script to run even before the google tag script is loaded. It will tell the google tag to set the consent values by default to denied, and later on in your custom cookie banner you can set the consent to true if the user clicked accept.

**Steps:**

1. Go to google tag manager, select your container
2. Click your tag id in the overview op (eg GTM-XXXXXXX)
3. follow the instructions, add the snippets to your index.html page

*These 3 steps is what the initialize() function does in `react-gtm-module`*

Then,

4. add another snippet above the script that loads the google tag (above `<!-- Google Tag Manager -->`). This script will send the default consent values to google tag manager, before any other google tag actions are taken (this is what you want!!)

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager consent -->
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }

      if (localStorage.getItem('consentMode') === null) {
        gtag('consent', 'default', {
          ad_storage: 'denied',
          analytics_storage: 'denied',
          personalization_storage: 'denied',
          functionality_storage: 'denied',
          security_storage: 'denied',
        });
      } else {
        gtag('consent', 'default', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('consentMode')));
      }
    </script>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

5. add a `global.d.ts` if you are using typescript with

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    gtag: (...args: any[]) => void;
  }
}

export {};
```

6. now you can use gtag functions in your code.

```
  interface IConsentMode {
    necessary: boolean;
    marketing: boolean;
    analytics: boolean;
    preferences: boolean;
  }
  const setConsentMode = (consent: IConsentMode) => {
    const consentMode = {
      functionality_storage: consent.necessary ? 'granted' : 'denied',
      security_storage: consent.necessary ? 'granted' : 'denied',
      ad_storage: consent.marketing ? 'granted' : 'denied',
      analytics_storage: consent.analytics ? 'granted' : 'denied',
      personalization: consent.preferences ? 'granted' : 'denied',
    };
    window.gtag('consent', 'update', consentMode);
    localStorage.setItem('consentMode', JSON.stringify(consentMode));
  };
```

references:

- code example: https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga4-tutorials/blob/main/src/public/partials/consent.eta
- instruction source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9976101
- instruction video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqAEbshMv84&t=220s&ab_channel=GoogleAnalytics

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to do anything special programming-wise.

It'll be more of a configuration in GTM.

There are many community templates that manages this, but I would go with Simo Ahava's https://www.simoahava.com/custom-templates/consent-mode/

Just search for it when adding a new tag in GTM.

Then you'll be able to push to the datalayer with certain events with the update, shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I am very confused: I built my custom consent form. I save user's preferences in a cookie with my own name. How does GTM know anything about that? I thought I have to call `window.gtag('consent', ...)`, but the react-gtm-module doesn't event populate the `window.gtag` function. Where is the connection between my own cookie form and GTM?

Comment: So it seems the answer is the GTM Template API as described in this article https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/consent-settings-google-tag-manager/
Now I only have to find out how to use the API in React.

Comment: Take a look at the screenshot, you really just have to "push" events to the datalayer the same way you've been doing it now. Except the event name is "gtm_consent_update" once you have Simo's consent tag installed in your GTM container. Of course you'll need to also include the correct variable names, values of what to update.

Comment: You were right, `dataLayer.push()` was enough. I did not understand its relationship with the `gtag()` function and was confused by the fact that the Google documentation did not include the `dataLayer.push()` calls. Thank you

Comment: can you give me an example of this dataLayer.push()? what is passed in the function?